# Can time complexity of this code be further reduced?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, c++11

I am getting a timeout for several test cases of a programming challenge. Any help will be appreciated.

That's the exercise:

> A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The smallest 6 digit palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers is `101101 = 143 * 707`.
>
> Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers which is less than `N` (any input greater than `101101` and less than `1000000`).

What I have is this:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
bool check_palindrome(unsigned int a)
{
 
       unsigned int temp = a;
       unsigned int digit ;        //used for reversing
       unsigned int rev_a = 0;    //final reversed number
       int power = 5;             //used for reversing
       unsigned int modulo;       //used for reversing
    while(temp > 0)
    {
        digit = temp / int(pow(10,power));
        temp = temp % int(pow(10 , power));
        rev_a = rev_a + digit * (pow(10 , 5 - power));
        power--;
            
    }
return (a == rev_a) ? true : false ; 
    }

int main()
{
int T;
unsigned int n;

scanf("%d" , &T);
for(int i = 0 ; i < T ; i++)             //for entering number of test cases
    {
    unsigned int max_palindrome=0;
    scanf("%d" , &n);                    //Input the number
    for(int p = 101  ; p <= 999 ; p++)
        {
            int m ;
            int other_number = int(n/p);
            if(other_number > 999 )
                 m = 999;
            else 
                m = other_number;
                
            for( int q = m ; q >100 ; q--)
            {
                if( p*q < 101101)
                       break;
                bool palindrome = check_palindrome(p*q);
                    if(palindrome)
                        {
                            if(p*q > max_palindrome)
                                max_palindrome = p*q;
                                break;
                        }
            }
            
        
        
       }
        printf("%d\n" , max_palindrome);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a lookup table instead of repeatedly calling `pow`.  Also, don't use this abomination: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`.

Comment: @Deepanshu  Dont you think precomputing palindrome numbers will increase time complexity ?? In my code , I am updating the max_palindrome at every iteration ?

Comment: `long powTable [] = {1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000};.. digit = temp / powTable[power];...`  Something like this.  Calling `pow` not only is slower and uses floating point, it isn't guaranteed to return the correct value, even if integers are used.

Comment: #include<bits/stdc++.h>  Does this contribute in execution time ??  I think that it just effects compilation time.

Comment: It is an advice for code improvement.  A lot of these "coding challenges" contribute to the most horrid coding standards known.

Comment: If you are not restricted in code size then you could write a program, like the one you've got, to generate a table of all palindromic numbers that are products of three digit numbers between the limits as a header file that is included in the program you submit to the contest, which program just searches the table, given N.

Comment: @dmuir How storing all the palindromic numbers will improve time complexity of my code. I have used the same logic to calculate maximum of them . Dont you think storing all of them and then searching the maximum among them will  take more time ?

Comment: I suggest you have two programs. One to generate the table. The other, that you submit to the contest, has the table compiled in. The performance of the first program is irrelevant to the contest.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie! powTable[] worked!! Execution time reduced from 0.33 to 0.03 seconds!!! But still I am getting timeouts for other test cases .. Anything more you would like to suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying all reasonable pairs of factors you could start from the given number and count down. Each time you come to a palindromic number, see if it can be expressed as a suitable product (checking all possible factors from `sqrt(palindrome)` down to 101).

The advantage is that as soon as you find a suitable palindrome you're done, you don't have to keep searching.

EDIT: You don't even have to search for palindromes, you can just enumerate them by working through all possible front halves and computing the corresponding back halves.

Answer (score 0):

As @AlanStokes said, you're checking more values than you need.  In addition, here's a more reasonable palindrome check.

```
bool is_palindrome(unsigned n) {
  unsigned rn = 0;
  for (unsigned x = n; x; x /= 10)
    rn = 10 * rn + x % 10;
  return rn == n;
}
```